# Oracle SQL convenient way to use Git version control

Tags: git, oracle, version-control, oracle-sqldeveloper

What is the convenient way to use Git for Oracle SQL Developer?

SQL Developer has Team tab which has some commands related to Git but the way how they work is so not convenient.

There are no projects, I have to stay in the file to see possible actions for this file, history is not informative, I cannot compare different versions, etc.

So far the only way what I see is to use Git command line to manage files.
Also working with files instead of the database itself is not convenient too.

Maybe I'm too used for good IDEs in other languages (like Eclipse) but it looks ridiculously ineffective how SQL Developer works with versions.

I can use these other tools or some plugins in Eclipse to work with SQLs. But then I cannot use SQL features like code suggestions.

Maybe Oracle uses other solutions? Oracle cloud?
Or, maybe, SQL developers do not need to use version control?
That I doubt - most probably they simply don't know what advantages it provides.

Right now I feel like I'm writing Java code in a notepad. It could be done but nobody does it.

Any suggestions on how to marry Oracle SQL and Git?

Comment: I am using GIT hub for my versioning and promoting codes to higher environments. I will clone in my GIT and for minor code changes use notepad ++ to edit and or major change I will replace file ... then stage changes and then commit and finally push .

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm forced to do - use notepad to write Java code. Not good solution for me...